# Debugging based on a debug level without performance impact?

Tags: python

In a web application I am writing, I have used the following:

```
def dbgmsg(lvl, fmt, ...):
    if dbglvl >= lvl:
        # ... format and write the message
        pass # just here for correctness
```

Which is then used inside the code as:

```
dbgmsg(3, "Something happened")
```

Since there is no thing such as a the `#ifdef` in Python to my knowledge, I need to include the code at runtime. Will the above code cause a performance impact due to the call being made even when the globally set `dbglvl` is `0`? Which alternatives exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It's going to take some time for Python to run the test `dbglvl >= lvl`. You can estimate the amount of time using the [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module. For example, on my computer,

   ```
   >>> from timeit import timeit
   >>> def f1():
   ...     pass
   ... 
   >>> def f2():
   ...     if x > 0:
   ...         pass
   ... 
   >>> x = 0
   >>> timeit(f1)
   0.14283514022827148
   >>> timeit(f2)
   0.18653011322021484
   ```

   So the `if x > 0:` test costs about 40 ns. If this is going to be a problem for you, then Python is probably not a suitable language for your application.
2. You can avoid the test altogether by having a separate name for the logging function at each debug level and then assigning a no-op function to the levels that don't apply.

   ```
   def debug_message_write(format, *args):
       debug_output.write(format.format(*args))

   def debug_message_ignore(format, *args):
       pass

   debug_message_1 = debug_message_write if debug_level >= 1 else debug_message_ignore
   debug_message_2 = debug_message_write if debug_level >= 2 else debug_message_ignore
   # etc.
   ```

   (You could avoid the repetition here by writing to the [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) dictionary in a loop.)

   And then in the code you would call

   ```
   debug_message_3("Opening {}", filename)
   ```

   or whatever. But this is more complicated than your original approach and I doubt that the minuscule saving in time is worth it.
3. Your code would be easier to read if you wrote `debug_message` instead of `dbgmsg` and `debug_level` instead of `dbglvl`. There is no need for you to save on vowels: there is no danger of running out.